# Export multiple tables as a single excel with input cells in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I am trying to export multiple tables as a single excel worksheet. I am able to do that if I don't have any input cells. I have one tables where I have input cells. in this case there is no data for those cells. below is the code that I am using.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS HTML Tables to Excel</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="export_table_to_excel_1">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input Hi></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hey</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>

  </table>

  <table id="export_table_to_excel_2">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Night</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Evening</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nite</td></tr>

  </table>

  <!--export excel button-->
  <a id="dlink" style="display:none;"></a>
  <input type="button" onclick="tablesToExcel(array1, 'Sheet1', 'myfile.xls')" value="Export to Excel">
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //table to excel (multiple table)
    var array1 = new Array();
    var n = 2; //Total table
    for ( var x=1; x<=n; x++ ) {
        array1[x-1] = 'export_table_to_excel_' + x;
    }
    var tablesToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>'
            , templateend = '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head>'
            , body = '<body>'
            , tablevar = '<table>{table'
            , tablevarend = '}</table>'
            , bodyend = '</body></html>'
            , worksheet = '<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>'
            , worksheetend = '</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>'
            , worksheetvar = '{worksheet'
            , worksheetvarend = '}'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            , wstemplate = ''
            , tabletemplate = '';

        return function (table, name, filename) {
            var tables = table;
            var wstemplate = '';
            var tabletemplate = '';

            wstemplate = worksheet + worksheetvar + '0' + worksheetvarend + worksheetend;
            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; ++i) {
                tabletemplate += tablevar + i + tablevarend;
            }

            var allTemplate = template + wstemplate + templateend;
            var allWorksheet = body + tabletemplate + bodyend;
            var allOfIt = allTemplate + allWorksheet;

            var ctx = {};
            ctx['worksheet0'] = name;
            for (var k = 0; k < tables.length; ++k) {
                var exceltable;
                if (!tables[k].nodeType) exceltable = document.getElementById(tables[k]);
                ctx['table' + k] = exceltable.innerHTML;
            }

            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(allOfIt, ctx));;
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Also let me know, how to add headers to the excel. And export as a single pdf

Thanks in advance